# How to structure a model in Flutter and Firebase after null safety

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on a project using flutter and after some changes were done in the package, I had problems creating new models for my apps. Currently, I created this model:

```
// @dart=2.9


import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserModel {
  String uid;
  String name;
  String email;
  int posts;
  String profileImage;
  Timestamp lastSeen;

  UserModel({this.uid, this.name, this.email, this.profileImage, this.posts, this.lastSeen});

  factory UserModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot _snapshot) {
    var _data = _snapshot.data;
    return UserModel(
      uid: _snapshot.id,
      name: _data["name"],
      email: _data["email"],
      profileImage: _data["profileImage"],
      posts: _data["posts"],
      lastSeen: _data["lastSeen"],
    );
  }
}
```

and flutter highlights the data inside the brackets with the following message "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object Function()'. "

Any idea on what's going on here and what has changed and how we can fix it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use .data on the snapshot you can fetch data by simply `_snapshot['yourKey']`

Code:-

```
class Users
{
  final String? id;
  final String? name;
  final String? email;

  Users({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
  });

  factory Users.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc)
  {
    return Users(
      id: doc.id,
      name: doc['name'],
      email: doc['email'],
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can add rest of the fields like this...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the data function to get the data.  inside your code, you are simply copying the functions and treating it as data. call the function like: `var _data = _snapshot.data();` you need the closing parenthesis **`()`** to call the function and get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Null Safety

```
factory UserModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot _snapshot) {
  Map<String, dynamic> _data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return UserModel(
    uid: _snapshot.id,
    name: _data["name"],
    email: _data["email"],
    profileImage: _data["profileImage"],
    posts: _data["posts"],
    lastSeen: _data["lastSeen"],
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).